# Python Multiprocessing program cause windows crash after 100%CPU utilization

Tags: python, windows, python-multiprocessing, multiprocess

I am using multiprocessing pool.map for read data from csv files, process the data and write back into different format in xlsx file.
I have 8 core processor on windows 10 machine, but I am only using 4 processes for this program, but it is still going with 100% cpu utilization as processing takes long time.
My windows 10 machine getting shut down every time the cpu utilization reaches 100 % and I am not able to execute the program fully. Can any one suggest how to avoid total 100% cpu utilization in pool.imap or prevent windows to shutdown when it occurs.

```
def _run_multiprocess(self,num_process,input_list,target_func,chunk):    
    iterator_result = None
    retVal = None
    l = mp.Lock()
    with mp.Pool(processes=(num_process),initializer=self.process_init, initargs=(l,)) as p:
        start = time.time()
        iterator_result  = p.imap(target_func, input_list,chunksize =chunk)
        p.close()
        p.join()
        end = time.time()
    return iterator_result
```

Comment: Do you have 8 physical cores or logical ones?

Comment: Its 8 logical cores. os.cpu_count() gives me 8 .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is either a hardware (overheating) or an OS problem; not a programming question. There are millions of servers worldwide, including Windows servers, which run at 100% CPU for hours at a time.